# How can I stop a radio button from unchecking after I push the submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, radio-button

I'm trying to stop my radio button from automatically unchecking after I've pushed the submit button. Here I've created a function that is supposed to check the right radio button after the form was submitted, but that doesn't work. I'm also pretty sure there's a better way to solve this.

My code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Arbeitsverhältnis:</h1> 
     <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="radio" name="arbeitstyp" value="arbeiter" id="arbeiter"/>Arbeiter</input>
    <input type="radio" name="arbeitstyp" value="angestellter" id="angestellter"/>Angestellter</input>
    <input type="radio" name="arbeitstyp" value="lehrling" id="lehrling"/>Lehrling</input>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="ausgabe" value="ausgabe">Ausgabe</button>
</form>

    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    
    <script>
    function check() 
    {
        document.getElementsByName('arbeiter').checked;
    }
</script>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['ausgabe'])){
    
        if($_POST['arbeitstyp'] == "arbeiter"){
            echo "Deine Arbeitszeit beginnt um 07:00 Uhr.";
            echo '<script>check();</script>';
        
        }
        else if($_POST['arbeitstyp'] == "angestellter"){
            echo "Deine Arbeitszeit beginnt um 08:00 Uhr.";
            echo '<script>check();</script>';
        }
        else if($_POST['arbeitstyp'] == "lehrling"){
            echo "Deine Arbeitszeit beginnt um 08:30 Uhr.";
            echo '<script>check();</script>';
        }
        else {
            echo "bitte wähle etwas aus.";
        }
    }
    ?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two issues: 1. `.getElementsByName()` returns either a NodeList or an HTMLElementCollection (depending on browser). That means there is more than one returned by your statement. 2. `.checked` is a Boolean attribute -so you need an assignment statement in order to check it - `.checked = true;`

Answer (score -1):

It will be cool to use flash session in PHP.
There are 2 scenarios you want to display the selected radio button.
Either after validation or after successful transaction.

Now if you use flash session in both logic, You can catch that flash session and display in your radio button.